# how do I set a button's text to be a field of an object I created?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I created a class called **Category** with a member that's a list, of type **Dish** (another class I created). I'm trying to create a grid container of buttons that display a button for each dish in the list and that the button's text will match the dishes name. I'm using a for loop to create the buttons but when I try adding the button text as the dish name "`btn.innerText = categor.dishes[i].name;`" nothing shows up. I think I don't quite have the hang of creating a list and an object and how to call upon an object's field in javascript. please let me know what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way of going about this, and any advice will be highly appreciated. TIA

this is class dish

```
public class Dish
    {
        public string name;
        public int price;

        public Dish(string foodName, int foodPrice)
        {
            name = foodName;
            price = foodPrice;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

this is class category

```
  public class category
        {
            public string name;
            public IList<Dish> dishes;

            public category(string Name, IList<Dish> Dishes)
            {
                name = Name;
                IList<Dish> dishes = Dishes;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the code in view

```
  <style>
        .categories-buttons {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px 80px 80px;
        }


        .item {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--  <div class="categories-buttonsDisplay">

    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="0" disabled />-->

    <div class="categories-buttons">
    </div>

    <script>
        var dish1 = { name: sweetpatato, price: 64 };
        var dish2 = { name: mushroom, price: 89 };
        var dish3 = { name: halomi, price: 76 };
        var list = { dish1, dish2, dish3 };
        var categor = { name: salads, dishes: list };
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName("categories-buttons")[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var btn = document.createElement("button");
            btn.innerText = categor.dishes[i].name;
            div.append(btn);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the list.length will give you undefined because list is created like an object, not like an array, so you should replace the curly brackets with these '[', ']'

secondly, you will get an error when you set the name. in order to set a string you should set them like this: name: 'sweetpatato'

here is a working sample of the code:

```
<style>
.categories-buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px 80px 80px;
}


.item {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="categories-buttons">
</div>

<script>
var dish1 = { name: 'sweetpatato', price: 64 };
var dish2 = { name: 'mushroom', price: 89 };
var dish3 = { name: 'halomi', price: 76 };
var list = [dish1, dish2, dish3];
var categor = { name: 'salads', dishes: list };

var div = document.getElementsByClassName("categories-buttons")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerText = categor.dishes[i].name;
    div.append(btn);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much!!!. just a quick question, is there a way to use css so the  button size will adjust itself to the text and all the buttons will be the same size?

Comment: You are welcome! I would use display: flex instead of grid and add fill-grow on all children elements to fill the whole top portion of the screen with buttons that have the same width.